# echo the sum in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to show all rows in an HTML table and in a final line, I want to make the sum of Pay column and show it.
I have an SQL query that select all from a table:

```
<?php
        $selectAll = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date";
        $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll);
        $stmtAll->bindValue(':date', date("y-m-d"));
        $execAll=$stmtAll->execute();
        $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll();
      ?>
```

It shows me all data in an html table. But when I added this to the query:

```
<?php
        $selectAll = "SELECT sum(pay) as total, sales.* FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date";
        $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll);
        $stmtAll->bindValue(':date', date("y-m-d"));
        $execAll=$stmtAll->execute();
        $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll();
      ?>
```

And then in a new row : `<?php echo $rows['total'] ?>` it shows me only one row of all the table but the total is echoed properly.

Comment: what is your sum for?

Comment: mean sun for sales.id, sales.invoice_id?

Comment: i want to show all rows in html table and after the loop of foreach finish, I want to add a new line that make the sum of all column called Pay.

Comment: `sum` is an `aggregating` function. You could try perhaps `select 
 ( select sum(pay) from sales where date_now = :date ) as total, 
 * from sales where date_now = :date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you should remove sum from your query to be like the first query, and you have 2 choice to get sum:

1- run next query to get the sum:

```
SELECT sum(pay) as total FROM sales WHERE date_now = :date
```

2- through your php code, by make var `$sum = 0;` then add the values of pay in your loop for the first query `$sum = $sum + $rows['total'];`

this because the sum in the query, work as collect set of rows and make a summation for all values of pay every group by, for example if you want sum of all pays in the invoice field you do: `select sum(pay) from sales group by invoice_id`, and if you didn't use `group by` you will sum all sales rows like your query do.